# JavaScript regexp for phone number does not match

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

I would like to ask for help with following issue:

I have following regexp:

```
var r = /^(\+455\ )(\d{3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})$/
```

i would like to use this regexp to replace number and separate this number by spaces, for example like this : "+455 123 123 123".

I was expecting, that regexp above will do following job: when i have "+455 " and 4 digits, it would return this:
"+455 123 1", but it only works from 5th digit in second group and output is following:

`'+455 1111'.replace(r,"$1$2 $3 $4");` is returning this: `'+455 1111'` (i expected `+455 111 1`)

and `'+455 11121'.replace(r,"$1$2 $3 $4");` is returning this: `'+455 111 2 1'` (I expected `+455 111 21`)

Can anyone help pls and let me know, where I am doing mistake in declaring regexp? Or anywhere else...

Thank you in advance.

Brgds,
Tom

Comment: You can make the last group optional `^(\+455 )(\d{3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})?$` https://regex101.com/r/FtYfs9/1

Comment: Thank you very much for help, it works...its just adding space after replaced value, but its ok with trim, `'+455 111222'.replace(r,"$1$2 $3 $4").trim();` , finally I found out, that solution is salso update regexp to `^(\+455 )(\d{3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})?$` which also works with trim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `^(\+455 )(\d{3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})$` matches at least 5 digits due to the `{1,3}` in the quantifiers.

If you make the last group optional, there can be a match for the 3rd group from the 7th - 9th digit in group 4

You can omit the backslash before the space as well in this part `\`

```
^(\+455\ )(\d{3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5umOz/1)

```js
const regex = /^(\+455 )(\d{3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})?$/;
[
  "+455 123123123",
  "+455 1111",
  "+455 11121"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1$2 $3 $4"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments. You can make the last group optionnal to avoid it to match on the digits that you wish to put in the second group.

With some corrections, you can use this regex : `^(\+455)\ ?(\d{3})\ ?(\d{1,3})?\ ?(\d{1,3})?`
In the changes, I've added a non mandatory space between each group, I've moved the space out of the first group to make the same thing on every group. So now you should do :

```js
let regex = /^(\+455)\ ?(\d{3})\ ?(\d{1,3})?\ ?(\d{1,3})?$/;
console.log("+455111222333".replace(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4"));
console.log("+455111".replace(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4"));
console.log("+45511122".replace(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4"));
console.log("+4551112223".replace(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4"));
console.log("+455111 22".replace(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4"));
console.log("+455111 22".replace(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4"));
console.log("+455123 12345".replace(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4"));
```